# C# 2 if statements

Tags: c#

i'm trying to write a code

```
if (question == 1)
        {
            if (textAnswer.Text.Equals("adult"))
            {
                points = points + 500;
                scoreLabel.Text = "POINTS : " + points;
                okuB();

            }
            else if (textAnswer.Text != "adult")
            {
                points = points - 250;
                scoreLabel.Text = "POINTS : " + points;

            }

        }
```

if user writes adult he will earn 500 points , if he writes something else he'll lose 250 points.When i write incorrent first i lose 250 points after that i write correct word but i get 250 points not 500.How can i fix this ? I started with 1000 points

Comment: Well, if you started with 0 points then order of program says that it would be: **`0 => 0 - 250 => -250 => -250 + 500 => 250`**; it's actually correct then.

Comment: I assume you running this code multiple times for the same question? Can't you only run it once, at the end maybe when they can no longer change their answer?

Comment: this is more of a math problem than a coding problem

Comment: I started with 1000 points you clever boys. 
1000 - 250 = 750 after i write adult it increases to 1000 again not to 1250.

Answer (score 2):

If you had 0 points and lost 250 you have now **-250 points**
Then you earned 500 now you have -250 + 500 = **250 points**

You can improve your `IF` statements too - no need to re-check:

```
if (question == 1)
    {
        if (textAnswer.Text.Equals("adult")) {
            points += 500;
            okuB();
        } else {
            points -= 250;
        }
        scoreLabel.Text = "POINTS : " + points;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you answer incorrectly it subtracts 250 from `points`, so `points == -250` (assuming it started at 0.)

When you answer correctly it adds 500.
-250 + 500 = 250.

---

I neglected to answer the question - "How do I fix this?"

```
        if (textAnswer.Text.Equals("adult"))
        {
            points = 500; 
            scoreLabel.Text = "POINTS : " + points;
            okuB();

        }
```